# Why does this call to Moq from F# throw an exception?

Tags: f#, moq

I believe it has something to do with the use of the `times` argument on `Verify()`.

```
open NUnit.Framework
open Moq

type IService = abstract member DoStuff : unit -> unit

[<Test>]
let ``Why does this throw an exception?``() =
    let mockService = Mock<IService>()
    mockService.Verify(fun s -> s.DoStuff(), Times.Never())
```

Exception message:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moq's `Verify` method has many overloads, and without an annotation F# will by default resolve the expression you specified to the overload expecting a `Func<IService,'TResult>` where `'TResult` is unit, which explains the failure at runtime.

What you want to do is to explicitly use the overload of `Verify` which takes an `Action`.

One option is to use the [Moq.FSharp.Extensions](http://trelford.com/blog/post/MoqEx.aspx) project (available as a package on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.FSharp.Extensions/)) which among other things adds 2 extension methods `VerifyFunc` & `VerifyAction` making it easier to resolve F# functions to Moq's C# based `Action` or `Func` arguments:

```
open NUnit.Framework
open Moq
open Moq.FSharp.Extensions

type IService = abstract member DoStuff : unit -> unit

[<Test>]
let ``Why does this throw an exception?``() =
   let mockService = Mock<IService>()
   mockService.VerifyAction((fun s -> s.DoStuff()), Times.Never())
```

Another option is to use [Foq](http://trelford.com/blog/post/FoqItEasy.aspx), a Moq like mocking library specifically designed for F# users (also available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foq)):

```
open Foq

[<Test>]
let ``No worries`` () =
  let mock = Mock.Of<IService>()
  Mock.Verify(<@ mock.DoStuff() @>, never)
```

Comment: I think you mean the nuget package adds the VerifyFunc and VerifyAction extension methods, not overloads.